# Frame grabbing with VLC

Tags: wpf, h.264, vlc, frame-grab

I used VLC.DotNet dlls to play my RSTP/h.264 stream in my WPF application. Now, I need to process some frames of this stream.
Does VLC.DotNet have any methods for frame grabbing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Vlc.DotNet library (https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet / Nuget: Vlc.DotNet.Wpf/Core/Core.Interop/Forms) doesn't have snapshot functionality yet. It seems to have been implemented in the Core library but not in the actual VlcControls so hopefully it'll show up sometime soon.

The *old* Vlc.DotNet library, which I think you can still acquire here: https://github.com/RexGrammer/Vlc.DotNet-Deprecated , should allow snapshots using the following:

```
myVlcControl.TakeSnapshot(@"C:\", 1280, 720);
```